# What is the correct procedure for shutting down a Windows 2008 Cluster?

Tags: windows-server-2008, cluster

We are trying out a Windows 2008 R2 Cluster server at the moment.

What is the correct sequence of events for shutting down a cluster for maintenance?

Comment: You want to shut the whole cluster down? I'd suggest you take your cluster resources offline with the cluster admin snapin, then do whatever maintenance you require. But, do you really need to take the services offline for your work to go ahead?

Comment: Exactly. For maintenance you DO NOT SHUT DOWN THE CLUSTER. You move resources freeing X servers which you maintain, in some sort of rolling maintenance.

Comment: We want to shut the cluster down for maintenance to the power in the data centre.  What we do not want is whilst someone is working, they break the power supply to the servers and they go down hard.  Better that they are off-line for a short time.

Comment: In which case, yep, take your cluster resources offline then go through a normal Windows shutdown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take the cluster resources offline and proceed to windows shutdown. BTW, is your application cluster aware? How was the app configured: as generic service or as a registered clustrer app?